# Need to hide id in my RewriteRule in .htaccess

Tags: php, mysql, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have built a custom business directory in PHP and I'm making the URLs human readable.

My URL request for getting business sub directories is:

```
http://.../new/business-subdirectory.php?cat=air-conditioners&cid=281
```

So I have written a rule in my .htaccess which gives me pretty well URL

```
http://.../business-directory/air-conditioners/281
```

Since my MySQL queries working on IDs, so I have to pass the ID **(281)** in the Pretty URL but I don't want it in the URL.

I just want the Pretty URL to be:

```
http://.../business-directory/air-conditioners/
```

Here is my .htaccess rule:

```
RewriteRule ^business-directory/(.*)/(.*)/?$ new/business-subdirectory.php?cat=$1&cid=$2
```

One option that I have is to use sub directories names instead of IDs... But still wanna see that I have other options or not...?

Waiting for your answers or suggestions :)

Omer

Comment: `/business-directory/air-conditioners/281` is pretty good scheme. See this questions's URL on SO that has question id as well.

Comment: How will your mysql query get Id parameter if it's not in the url?

Comment: That's why I have asked here... ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are performing queries based on ID passed in URL. So without changing code you can not achieve what you are looking.

Best option would be to have `slug` value in URL, which is unique same as your ID and you need to change your queries based on that.

so if `air-conditioners` is having ID `281` then you need to change your query to fetch data based on category slug and not using ID.

Comment: That's the option I have mentioned in my question... So I guess I have no other way... Thanks Avinash :)